# Arabic text displayed as question marks in QT application

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT 5.2.0 and I am trying to set the text of a QPushButton to some arabic text but when I run the program the text is displayed as question marks. I even tried this:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");

findButton = new QPushButton(codec->toUnicode("ابدأ"));
```

But its still not working. Any other solution?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your computer has Arabic fonts installed and available?

Comment: yes. It has Arabic fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Qt 5.3, the following code works for me on Windows 7:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QPushButton *findButton = new QPushButton(codec->toUnicode("ابدأ"));
    findButton->show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

It could be that this is [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35836) or [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36789). I'd suggest trying the code above with the [5.3 beta](http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.0-beta/) first.